# Union class with template type

Tags: flutter, riverpod, freezed

I'm trying to build a union type for api responses.

I found freezed package supports union types and I tried out without issues. But as the api return different classes (responses) I think using a template type is suitable to keep the class as generic as possible.

This is the file I created:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'api_response.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class ApiResponse<T> with _$ApiResponse {
  const factory ApiResponse.success(T content, String? message) = _Data;
  const factory ApiResponse.failed(String? message, Object? exception) = _Error;
}
```

But when the build_runner generates the part file, there is an error on it:

[image: error on generated file]

Is there a way to fix it? Or another way to implement it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as follows:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'test_union.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class TestUnion<T> with _$TestUnion<T> {
  const factory TestUnion.foo(T fubar) = _Foo<T>;
}
```

You can then use it as:

```
const foo = TestUnion<String>.foo("fubar");
```

So give this a go:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'api_response.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class ApiResponse<T> with _$ApiResponse<T> {
  const factory ApiResponse.success(T content, String? message) = _Data<T>;
  const factory ApiResponse.failed(String? message, Object? exception) = _Error;
}
```

Comment: It works as expected. I guess I have to define the template type to the mixin too in order to match up their types. Makes sense

Comment: Yepp. This seems to have been part of the original documentation, but was removed for some reason. Perhaps there is a better way of doing this nowadays. Search for Union<T> on https://pub.dev/packages/freezed/versions/0.14.0